# Stream read to specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I need to read txt file which contains something like below
123123; 192.168.1.1;
321321;192.168.2.1;
I want to read the text to a specific character for example ";"
and assign it to variable and label or use it within the code

after long search...

first way

```
  StreamReader office_list = new StreamReader(@"c:\office_list.txt");

var x = office_list.ToString();
var y = Regex.Match(x, @"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b");
Current_Office.Text = y.Value;
```

but that returns nothing .. and the second way I found

```
string [] cur_office = Regex.Split(office_list.ToString(), ";");
           foreach(string x in cur_office)
        {
            Current_Office.Text = x;
        }
```

but that returns System.IO.StreamReader... third way as below

```
Current_Office.Text = Regex.Match(office_list.ToString(), @"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b");
```

the error was 
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to 'string'   C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  23  35  WindowsFormsApplication1

Can anyone suggest something  or point me to the best way for capturing ips form text file that contains 1000 of the example above?

Answer (score 2):

I think your very first line is wrong.

```
var x = office_list.ToString();
```

Is office_list of type StreamReader?

try

```
var x = office_list.ReadLine();

string [] cur_office = Regex.Split(x, ";");
           foreach(string x in cur_office)
        {
            Current_Office.Text = x;
        }
```

Comment: subtle bug - nice catch!

Comment: yes office_list is StreamReader type i had edit my post it was missing... I tried whats u suggest but i got the full sting without any splitting (23123; 192.168.1.1) I thing split wont work here because its keep splitting to the end of string it will not stop untill the end of string while i want to stop on the first match of specific character

Comment: what was the value of cur_office after the split? did it have one or two entries in the array? what were the values?

Comment: ia had tested now and its return the whole string within the file that are on one line ex (0303; 14.0.0.300;0505; 14.0.0.500;) or (0303; 14.0.0.300;) or (0303; 14.0.0.300;0505; 14.0.0.500;0101; 14.0.0.100;0202; 14.0.0.200;0303; 14.0.0.300;)

Comment: If the file isn't too big, just do office_list.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all IP adresses in the following way:

```
using (var stream = new StreamReader(@"your path here"))
{
    var ipAddresses = stream
        .ReadToEnd()
        .Split(';')
        .Select(ip => ip.Trim()); // not sure if this one is needed, you can try without
    foreach (var ip in ipAddresses)
    {
        // do what you will with the ips
    }
}
```

Comment: thats works on the messgebox but the label show nothing

Comment: what label? ipAddresses is an IEnumerable<string> that contains all the ip-addresses from the file, can you confirm that it gets initialized correctly? given this, you should be able to do what you want with them. what is it that you want to accomplish but fail to?

Comment: i am using label to show user to under which ip he is connecting so i am assigning the ip to a label ]

Comment: which ip do you want to show? the first one in the file? in that case, you can access it by removing the foreach loop and appending `.FirstOrDefault()` after `Select` (and check the result for `null`).